# "The referenced component could not be found" but VS keeps re-adding the reference after I remove it

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.8

In my .net framework 4.8 project, in the References folder (in solution explorer) there are references to projects such as

`C:\Users\Owner\.nuget\packages\microsoft.web.webview2\1.0.1054.31\build\..\lib\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.winmd`

This does not exist.  I also don't need it, as separately I have a reference to WebView2.Core and so this line seems unnecessary.  I can delete it, and everything will build.  But when I close the solution and reopen in, it reappears.  This also produces warnings when I build.

Of note, I recently did the migration to `PackageReference`, so there's a `packages.config` file in addition to this `References` folder, but that file doesn't have `WebView2` so it doesn't seem relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bug with WebView2.  Updating to the latest using Nuget resolved the issue.  Explanation:

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1722